# Searchbar crashing when typing in a search character

Tags: uitableview, uisearchbar

Here is my problem, I cant seem to get past typing in 2 characters in the search bar with out the app crashing on me. The first one works as it should but when I search for any other butterfly other than the first one CRASH! Please help!
        [filteredComList removeAllObjects];
        [filteredImgList removeAllObjects];
        [filteredSciList removeAllObjects];

```
    [filteredComList addObjectsFromArray:buttComNameList];
    [filteredSciList addObjectsFromArray:buttSciNameList];
    [filteredImgList addObjectsFromArray:butterflyImages];

}else {

    [filteredComList removeAllObjects];
    [filteredImgList removeAllObjects];
    [filteredSciList removeAllObjects];

    for (NSString *string in buttComNameList) {
        NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
            [filteredComList addObject:string];
        }
    }
    for (NSString *string in buttSciNameList) {
        NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
            [filteredSciList addObject:string];
        }
    }
    for (NSString *string in butterflyImages) {
        NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
            [filteredImgList addObject:string];
        }
    }
}
[myButterflyTable reloadData];
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
_searchWasActive = NO;
[butterflySearchBar resignFirstResponder];
[self.tableView setFrame:self.view.bounds];

}
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
_searchWasActive = YES;
NSLog(@"began editing");
}
- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
_searchWasActive = NO;
NSLog(@"ended editing");
}
```

Table delegate methods below

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

// Return the number of rows in the section
return [filteredComList count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
Defenitions *def = [[Defenitions alloc]init];

// Configure the cell...

//[self fetchedResultsController:[self fetchedResultsControllerForTableView:tableView]    configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
if (_searchWasActive) {
    [def defineButterfly:[filteredComList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] defineLatin:   [filteredSciList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] setImage:[filteredImgList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}else {
    [def defineButterfly:[buttComNameList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] defineLatin:[buttSciNameList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] setImage:[butterflyImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
[cell.contentView addSubview:[def commonName]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:[def latinName]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:[def butterflyImage]];


return cell;
}
```